# Can docker host intercept local traffic inside a container?

Tags: docker, containers

Is it possible for the docker host to observe the communication between two processes running inside the same container? The processes use TCP on localhost for communication.

Most of the documentation I see talk about sniffing on the docker0 interface or any interface created by docker-compose. But this would be outbound/inbound traffic on the network interface. In my case all communication is local.

Comment: I don't know docker network stack very well though, you could intercept whatever with BPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I used bpftrace with tcpconnect.bt (or tcpaccept.bt)
as you can see it can observe container localhost to container localhost tcp connect (or accept)

if you want to more detail, you could write your own bpf program

Comment: and I think localhost to localhost packet would use lo interface not veth or docker0 interface. so common methodology couldn't intercept that packet I guess

Comment: Thanks. Came across this article - https://lwn.net/Articles/793749/ where a probe is attached to tcp_sendmsg function. It should be trivial to dump the message from the second parameter.